# ScaleType fitXY is not working on orientation change

Tags: android

I am working on app, on that images are being loaded from server side. To load those images I am using picasso library.When images are loaded firs time those are fine and fitXY but when I rotate screen to landscapestill those are fine but when I rotate again to portriat then images are not completely fitXY those have empty spaces on edges. Any help? Below is the code I am using

```
<com.gennext.widgets.ShadedImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/srch_listing"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/no_image_found" />
```

And below is the picasso code I am using

```
try{
        PicassoTrustAll.getInstance(getContext()).load(photo).fit().into(holder.photo, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                holder.photoLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                holder.photoLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.photo.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.no_image_found));
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex){}
```

Below is the screen shot of the screen when images are loaded first time and those are fine as expected

[image]

When I rotate to landscape still that is fine as shown in below image

[image]

But when I rotate back to portriat then here comes the problem as shown in below image

[image]

In last image, I have shown some line on the side of the images. Those extra spaces are the issues. Any help?

Comment: How you set no image can you please post code for that ?

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Reload the images when orientation changed

Comment: In adapter onCreateViewHolder() method you are passing parent or not while inflating the view, Share the adapter code